# Setting http headers processor:http-client

Tags: spring-xd

I would like to set User-Agent header when using processor:http-client

I see there is mappedRequestHeaders option, but how to use to set User-Agent: Mozilla for example

Either I am missing something or spring-xd lacking processor:header-enricher. This would do what I am looking for in regular Spring Integration context:

```
<int:chain id="mychain" input-channel="http-request-data">  
    <int:header-enricher>  
        <int:header name="User-Agent" value="curl/7.0.48"/>    
    </int:header-enricher>
    <int-http:outbound-gateway url="${url}"  http-method="GET" expected-response type="java.lang.String"/>      
    <int-file:outbound-channel-adapter directory="${output-folder}" filename-generator-expression="'${filename}'" />
</int:chain>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` has `request-factory` attribute and can inject to it `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` bean. This `ClientHttpRequestFactory` provides some default `User-Agent` header value.

Since it is your own Spring XD instance you can modify an existing `[XD_HOME]\xd\modules\processor\http-client\config\http-client.xml` adding that bean definition:

```
<bean id="requestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory"/>

<int-http:outbound-gateway request-factory="requestFactory"/>
```

Leaving everything other without changes.

In addition you should add `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5` jar to the `lib` of that `http-client` module.

The Commons HttpClient allows even to specify `httpclient.useragent` System property to override the default value.

Feel free to raise (https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD) an issue regarding `processor:header-enricher`.

Of course you can overcome it right now with the Groovy `script` processor:

```
org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload)
     .copyHeaders(headers)
     .setHeader('User-Agent', 'curl/7.0.48')
     .build()
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Groovy script approach is nice.. for now I added processor/header.xml : Groovy script approach is nice.. for now I added processor/header.xml - very simple I only needer one header

```
<channel id="input"/>

<header-enricher input-channel="input" output-channel="output">
    <header name="${name}" value="${value}"/>
</header-enricher>

<channel id="output"/>
```